# Screen share Pepper's tablet

Tags: javascript, python, nao-robot, pepper

How can I share the screen of Pepper's tablet? I wish to show the content displayed on the tablet on a projector so that it is engaging a larger audience. Is there any way to access it using the Java or Python SDK?

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: Is the answer the right one? if true, mark it as solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I often do that.

One way of doing so in NAOqi 2.5:

- Make a webpage for your tablet content, formatted so that it looks good both on Pepper's tablet and in a browser window (so you need to use responsive design). See [this](https://github.com/aldebaran/robot-jumpstarter#template-service-tabletpage), for example, on how to build a project with a basic webpage.
- Store your state on the robot-side, e.g. in a python script / service; and the webpage should just be a watcher of that state (e.g. subscribe to a signal on a service, or to an ALMemory key). If you have buttons on the webpage, they should not *directly* change the display, but rather notify the python, which will in turn update the state which will update the webpage.
- When running the application, display it on the tablet on usual AND with a web browser, open http://your-robots-ip/apps/your-app-id/, and put it in full sceen.

*Et voilà!* You should have a nice synchronized display on the tablet and the screen!

Comment: Thanks @Emile for the solution. It works great. I would like your help with two more points in this regards: 1. I believe that the screen share will not work when my webpage is sending/receiving some data from Choregraphe when the application is running. Is it correct? 2. I found that you used RobotUtils JS file in your html code. Is there any way I could learn about it more? A tutorial infact would be great.

Comment: 1. the screen share should work just fine when the app is running with Choregraphe; but if choregraphe does a showWebview or showImage that won't impact the share (but if all choregraphe does is raise ALMemory it works fine). 2: see https://github.com/pepperhacking/studiotoolkit/blob/master/doc/js_robotutils.md